# Creating a registration key

Tags: paypal

I am selling my software on line, and using PayPal for payment processing. Every time someone buys my software, I get notified by PayPal, at which point I take the purchaser's name and encrypt it onto a unique password with which they can unlock the software. I e-mail this password to the user.

I'd like to automate this step, so that every time PayPal processes the payment, the user name is used to create an unique password, and the email is sent directly to the user. Is that possible from PayPal's side?

Answer (score 0):

You have many options. For example:

- PayPal - Instant Payment Notification. Basically, everytime one of
  your clients buys your software PayPal will notify you using the url
  you set in your button for IPN. Please check the documentation
  [HERE](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/)
- Express Checkout. [DOCUMENTATION](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/)